# unit-testing on ionic service undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

happy holidays!, I'm facing an issue that I don't know why it's giving me:

//LoginCtrl:

```
angular.module('login.controller', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $translate, $ionicPopup, UserService, Auth) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {

    var onSuccess = function(response) {
      if (response.data.user !== null) {
        Auth.setUser(response.data.user);
        Auth.setToken(response.data.user.token);

        $state.go('app.main');
      } else if (response.data.result == 101) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
                   title: $translate.instant('login_error'),
                   template: $translate.instant('login_not_verified')
                 });
      }else {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
                   title: $translate.instant('login_error'),
                   template: $translate.instant('login_bad_password_text')
                 });
      }

    };

    var onError = function() {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
                 title: $translate.instant('login_error'),
                 template: $translate.instant('login_error_text')
               });
    };
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    UserService.login($scope.loginData.username, $scope.loginData.password).then(onSuccess, onError);

  };

  $scope.doRegister = function() {
    $state.go("register");
  };
});
```

// Login Ctrl Test

```
describe('LoginCtrl', function() {

  var controller,
      deferredLogin,
      userServiceMock,
      stateMock,
      scopeMock,
      ionicPopupMock;

  //Load the App module
  beforeEach(module('starter'));

  // Instantiate the Controller and Mocks

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $q, $rootScope, $translate, Auth) {
    deferredLogin = $q.defer();



    scopeMock = $rootScope.$new();

    // mock userServiceMock
    userServiceMock = {
        login: jasmine.createSpy('login spy')
                      .and.returnValue(deferredLogin.promise)
    };

    //mock $state
    stateMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$state spy', ['go']);

    //mock $ionicPopup
    ionicPopupMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$ionicPopup spy', ['alert']);

    //Instantiate LoginCtrl
    controller = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
      '$scope' : scopeMock,
      '$state' : stateMock,
      '$translate' : $translate,
      '$ionicPopup' : ionicPopupMock,
      'UserService' : userServiceMock,
      'Auth' : Auth
    });
  }));

  describe('#doLogin', function() {
    // Call doLogin on the Controllers
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      controller.$scope.loginData.username = 'test';
      controller.$scope.loginData.password = 'password';
      controller.$scope.doLogin();

    }));

    it('should call login on userService', function() {
      expect(userServiceMock.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test','password');
    });

    describe('when the login is executed,', function() {
      it('if successful, should change state to app.main', function() {

        //TODO: Mock the login response from userService

        expect(stateMock.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('app.main');
      });

      it('if unsuccessful, should show popup', function() {
        //TODO: Mock the login response from userService
        expect(ionicPopup.alert).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that when I execute the test when it executes expect(userServiceMock.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test','password'); it gives me the following error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userServiceMock.login') in unit-tests/login.controller.tests.js (line 56)

I don't know userServiceMock gives me undefined.

Thank you all, if you need more code or something say me please.

This is my karma conf:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Dec 26 2016 10:38:06 GMT+0100 (CET)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '../www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
      '../www/js/**/*.js',
      '../www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../www/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
      '../www/lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
      'unit-tests/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

Comment: It is possible if there were errors in `beforeEach`, so mock object wasn't assigned. Are there no other errors in the console? PhantomJS is known for swallowing errors, try to change it to Chrome launcher.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i will try now

Comment: @estus the problem was that the translate js was not defined in the conf. but now I have another error, the problem is that the controller is not initialized, I dont know why.

Comment: The problem stays the same. There should be an error that says what's the problem. If there's none, blame it on PhantomJS.

Comment: @estus I changed it to Chrome, but the problem is that all the variables are initalized but when I do the log of the variable controller I get an "{}" in the log

Comment: That's correct. It is controller's `this`. Since you don't use controllerAs here and apply changes to `$scope`, controller instance remains an empty object.

Comment: @estus I changed it to a variable var vm = this, and then assigned all to the vm variable and worked perfectly!, what's the best way? assing the variables doLogin, ... to the scope or tho the this vm variable?

Comment: The 'best practice' at this moment is to stick to controller instance and controllerAs syntax except for things that can be done only with $scope (built-in scope methods). As for the subject, there's no big difference in terms of testability, both ways can be tested nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not including translate libs on test.conf, and then that i was not taking the variables from the controller.